# UIApplication openUrl not working with formatted NSString

Tags: iphone, url, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiapplication

I have the following code to open google maps:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@, Anchorage, AK",addressString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

But it doesn't work and there is no error. It just doesn't open.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[URLWithString](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB) requires a percent-escaped string.  Your sample url contains spaces which results in a nil NSURL being created.  Additionally, the addressString may also contain characters that need to be escaped.  Try percent-escaping the url string first:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@, Anchorage, AK",addressString];
NSString *escaped = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Need to escape the urlString , 
else [NSURL URLWithString:urlString] will return nill.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@, Anchorage, AK",addressString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ]];
```