# Search location name in Google maps in ios app

Tags: ios, google-maps

I developed an app to open google map and search the given location name.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@",locationName]]];
```

i can't open the map for few location.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the location name for which the map is opening and for which the name is not opening?

Comment: Do these locations have spaces or other special characters in their name?  You'll need to escape those characters.

Comment: map open for the location FUZHOU, CHINA and for the location SAVANNAH, GA, UNITED STATES OF AMERICA is not opened.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534888/uiapplication-openurl-not-working-with-formatted-nsstring?answertab=active#tab-top)